# using fn: functions in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

How is this used?

usiing the example of fn:replace(string,pattern,replace)

is ist used as

```
  <xsl:value-of select="raplce(Bella Italia', 'l', '*')"/>
```

or

```
  <xsl:value-of select="fn:raplce(Bella Italia', 'l', '*')"/>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You don't need the `fn:` prefix but you misspellt the name of the function and there's a quote missing.

Comment: Why not trying yourself? The first example should be ok. The second assumes you have declared the XPath 2.0 namespace. Typos apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [XSLT 2.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#static-context):

> The default function namespace is the standard function namespace,
>   defined in [Functions and Operators]. This means that it is not
>   necessary to declare this namespace in the stylesheet, nor is it
>   necessary to use the prefix `fn` (or any other prefix) in calls to the
>   core functions.

However if you do use the `fn` prefix, then you must declare it as mapped to the [standard function namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#reserved-namespaces), e.g.

```
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
```